# OpenSSL 1.0.1e usage bug?

Tags: openssl

#### Environment

```
$ cat /etc/*-release
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)

$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

#### This works

```
$ tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/random | head -c 24 > ${f_host_passphrase}
$ echo -e "\n" >> ${f_host_passphrase}

$ openssl genpkey ... -pass file:${f_host_passphrase} -out ${f_host_key}

$ openssl req ... -key ${f_host_key} -passin file:${f_host_passphrase} \
    -out ${f_host_req}

$ openssl ca ... -in ${f_host_req} -out ${f_host_cert}

$ openssl pkcs12 \
  -export \
  -inkey ${f_host_key} \
  -passin pass:$(cat ${f_host_passphrase}) \
  -in ${f_host_cert} \
  -name "${l_ds_cert_name}" \
  -password file:${f_host_passphrase} \
  -out ${f_host_p12}

...

$ pk12util -i ${f_host_p12} \
  -w ${f_host_passphrase} \
  -d ${l_sql_prefix}${d_nssdb} \
  -k ${f_host_passphrase}

pk12util: PKCS12 IMPORT SUCCESSFUL
```

The full, functional script is [here](https://github.com/dafydd2277/systemAdmin/blob/master/ssl/99_resetSSL.sh). I wrote the script for rapid testing because, it turns out, this next variation fails.

#### This fails

```
$ tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/random | head -c 24 > ${f_host_passphrase}
$ echo -e "\n" >> ${f_host_passphrase}

$ openssl genpkey ... -pass file:${f_host_passphrase} -out ${f_host_key}

$ openssl req ... -key ${f_host_key} -passin file:${f_host_passphrase} \
    -out ${f_host_req}

$ openssl ca ... -in ${f_host_req} -out ${f_host_cert}

$ openssl pkcs12 \
  -export \
  -inkey ${f_host_key} \
  -passin file:${f_host_passphrase} \
  -in ${f_host_cert} \
  -name "${l_ds_cert_name}" \
  -password file:${f_host_passphrase} \
  -out ${f_host_p12}

...

$ pk12util -i ${f_host_p12} \
  -w ${f_host_passphrase} \
  -d ${l_sql_prefix}${d_nssdb} \
  -k ${f_host_passphrase}

pk12util: PKCS12 decode not verified: SEC_ERROR_BAD_PASSWORD: The security password entered is incorrect.
```

#### Why?

The only difference between the two variations (and the "failed" `openssl pkcs12` command is a comment block in the script to which I linked) is how I pass the passphrase file to the `openssl pkcs12` command.

If I send the passphrase as `-passin pass:$(cat ${f_host_passphrase})`, the following `pk12util` command succeeds.

If I send the passphrase as `-passin file:${f_host_passphrase}`, the `openssl pkcs12` command still succeeds, but the `pk12util` command fails.

My guess is that the `openssl pkcs12` command is parsing *something* as the password from the `-passin file:${f_host_passphrase}` argument. Just not what the rest of world is expecting to use...

Comment: I just posted this as a minor OpenSSL bug: http://bugs.centos.org/view.php?id=7854